# How to get unique elements through array and group them in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, iteration, grouping

i have issue. This below code is the views code of ruby in rails

```
<table >
<tr>
    <th>Url</th>
    <th>Tags</th>
</tr>   
 <% @array_bookmark = @bookmark.class == Array ? @bookmark : [@bookmark] %> 
 <% Array(@bookmark).each do |book| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= book.url %></td>
 <td><%= book.tags %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

This yields something like :

```
  Url                   Tags
 www.mrabhiram.tumblr.com   abhi
 www.mrabhiram.tumblr.com   blog
 google.com                 google
 google.com                 blog
```

But, i want to get it as

```
  Url                   Tags
 www.mrabhiram.tumblr.com   abhi,blog
 google.com                 google,blog
```

Can anyone provide me the solution? It should be generic enough to iterate over the array.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% Array(@bookmark).group_by {|b| b.url}.each do |url, books| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= url %></td>
    <td><%= books.map {|b| b.tags}.flatten.uniq.join(" ") %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group_by statement

upd

```
 <% Array(@bookmark).group_by(&:url).each do |url, books| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= url %></td>
 <td><%= books.map(&:tags).flatten.join(',') %></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: 'tags' would be array of books.

Comment: Logic is correct. Got the grouping. But got different elements. Any ways i got it. Look at above answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Array(@bookmark).uniq.each do |book| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= book.url %></td>
   <td><%= book.tags %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

the above will work.